# Adding a greeting message with fireworks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, json

This is an [eager](https://eager.io/app/fireworks/install) plugin which adds a greeting message with a custom image and fireworks to your site.

Preview of what it looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I implement this on my website with the help of its [github](https://github.com/EagerApps/Fireworks) page?

Here's my [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/2q5tLyyd/).

Comment: When you say "without using the eager plugin" what exactly do you mean? I assume you're not trying to re-write the thing.

Comment: not rewrite the whole thing, but get the code from its github page and add it to my site

Comment: Can I ask why using it through Eager is not a good option? Eager was built to make it easier to use tools like this without having to write code.

Comment: @ZackBloom also I'm experimenting a lot with this stuff so I might spark something up which you guys might find useful

Comment: @ZackBloom I'm also trying to customize even more stuff in this which is not possible through eager. I just need to know a way to get it work manually without using eager.

Comment: It might be possible to apply the customizations you need within Eager, if you want to shoot us an email -> help@eager.io.  Otherwise, the method would be to include most of app.js and app.css, tweaking the code where it refers to the `INSTALL_OPTIONS` object.